# Regular expressions to change a word with specific condition in perl

Tags: regex, perl, shell

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will change the suffix -ecek with -icek if the verb has -e -i letters in the racine. For example for 'gelecek' i want to obtain 'gelicek'. So far I have this:

```
$phone46=~s/(e|i)ecek/icek/g;
```

I don't want to say e or i followed by ecek, but i want to say e,i followed by any letters, +ecek. How can I improve (e|i) part to show that they can be followed by any caracter?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Sounds a bit unclear: Try `s/(?:e|i)(\p{L}*)cek/i$1cek/g`. Please provide sample strings and expected output.

Comment: How many letter should be allowed? Only one? Less than 5?

Comment: -ecek is the verb conjugasion suffix. so the racine of the verbe can have as much as possible. For example for guvenecek i want to have guvenicek. so i just want to say if there is e or i somewhere in the racine of the verb.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I well understand your needs, but how about:

```
$phone46 =~ s/([ei][a-z]*)ecek/$1icek/g;
```

This will replace `ecek` by `icek` when there is `e,i followed by any letters` before `ecek`

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you could go for something like this:

```
s/([ei][[:alpha:]]*)ecek\b/$1icek/g
```

This matches an `e` or `i`, followed by any number of alphabetic characters `[[:alpha:]]`, followed by `ecek`. The part in the parentheses is captured and used in the replacement.